# Relay Switching MCU Hanging/Reset

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, relay, high-voltage, emc

I am working on samD21 MCU to control the 16 relays. I am also using a circuit to detect the input AC switch status On/OFF (Connected serially to the relays). This is connected through optocoupler circuit and buffer IC. and the Relays are driven through ULN2003.
The PCB is pretty lengthy (27cmx10cm) and traces are little lengthy. I have used so many decaps and diodes closed to the relays.
The relays output connected to a 39 ohm 0.01uF snubber circuit. I checked with connecting 440V TVS diode also.
The real problem is whenever the switching happens MCU getting hang. Currently I connected to 10W LED Bulb as load
On the same 3V3 bus I hooked up a esp32 module (same board). which is havig no issues yet (shielded, only uart communication to SAMD21. no long traces other than uart routing).
Help me to figure this out.
I have attached schematics and layout. let me know any more info needed.[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show us _all_ the MCU connections, and the power supply circuit. "whenever the switching happens MCU getting hang." - does it still happen if 230V is not applied to the relay contacts?

Comment: Issue is only when connecting the AC supply.
I hope you are asking for all mcu pins connection. I have attached the same. Let me know this will work?

Comment: Issue occurs with AC supply and a LED lightbulb as a load on the relays, right? Try with no load (230V connected but no bulb) and also with a different load, like a low power incandescent bulb which does not have a filter capacitor causing inrush current. Also try connecting the load to different relays on your board. Do all relays cause the crash or just the ones on the left side of the board?

Comment: Also you can try clamping a big ferrite on the 24V power supply cable to check if it is a common mode issue. Why is there a big split in the DGND plane? What was your intent? Why 2 relay contacts in series?

Comment: @Peufeu. Issue occurs with LED bulb. No laod no issues. For incandescent I will gey back to you. Almost all relays having same problem. Its inconsistent also, once in a while the resetting happening. Not always.

Comment: Its really not a reset. The mcu will hang, like if all the relays are in ON, when this is happen all relays will go OFF and mcu is in freeze until next power cycle.

Comment: I have added a safety rated 1nF/400V cap across Dgnd and Wall ground(230V ground). This will reduce common noise?

Comment: I am using meanwell 24v/6A smps. I made the board as two ground one is for all the relays (high current), second one mcu and other low power electronics and connected in the source point. Since i have same issue with the previous board.

Comment: The load can be operate through manual switch also. At Normal condtion, the switch status detected by mcu and trigger the load relay accordingly. Second relay help only,  if the mcu down, it will ensure the closed loop and no interrupt to the service

Comment: Issue is more common when switching off the lamp. For ceiling condition is even worst.